# What is the difference between "regardless" and "irrelevant"?

Tags: differences

They are both adjective that mean not relating to something. Are the terms interchangeable?

Comment: This comment could be *irrelevant*, *regardless* of how I used those two words to mean different things.

Comment: Note that your question received 4 close-votes as it lacks your own research efforts. Please show us what you found and what still bothers you. Otherwise, we can't wright a definitive answer.

Comment: These are not especially similar terms. I recommend that you look both of them up in a dictionary and compare the definitions you find there. But because the meanings of the two words are so different, I don't think that this question will be of much interest to other readers long-term.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because few people besides the reader are likely to have trouble distinguishing between the two words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they are completely different. “Irrelevant” means something is not related to what is being discussed or considered and therefore not important. “Regardless” is just another word for “despite” or “not being affected by something”.

Examples from [(Cambridge dictionary)](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/regardless):

> 1)  It was pouring with rain, but we pressed on **regardless**.
>
> 2) Making a large profit is **irrelevant** to us - the important thing is to
>   make the book available to the largest possible audience.